# My Swift app is crashing with SIGABRT

Tags: swift, xcode, sigabrt

I am programing from the book coding iOS apps for kids at ioskids.com and I keep getting this error and I was wondering what this is and how to fix it.

Here is the error:

[image: My error]

Here is my code for the page the error was on:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        self.saveContext()
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data stack

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Birthdays")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support

    func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hopefully someone else is getting the same issue. I am getting this code from the book iOS Kids.

Comment: The error is not in this file. Assuming a standard project setup, there is probably something going wrong in your `ViewController.swift` file. A lot more context is needed to actually help you. What does the console say when you get the `SIGABRT`?

Comment: you can find more details about the error in console, you should copy output here.

Comment: Nevermind i fixed it